# I want to know why $\omega \neq \omega+1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In Kunen's book, Set Theory,chapter I.7, he said: $1+\omega=\omega \neq \omega+1$.
I want to know why $\omega \neq \omega+1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you write out the definitions? Note that $\omega+1$ has a ... element.

Comment: As an ordered set, $\omega +1$ has a largest element, while $\omega$ doesn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an easy way to see this. You need to apply the definition of ordinal addition:
$$\omega + 1  = \omega \times \{0\} \cup \{1\} \times \{1\} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots 1^\prime\}$$

So $\omega + 1$ has an element at the end that is not a successor of anything while $\omega$ does not.

On the other hand, $$1 + \omega  = \{1\} \times \{0\} \cup  \omega \times \{1\} = \{1 ^\prime, 0, 1, 2, \dots\} \cong \omega$$

so you see that addition doesn't commute.

There is some more information about this [here on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition) Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. The $\omega+1$ being seen as the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, \dots 1^\prime \}$ help me a lot.

Comment: @John Yes, it helped me a lot, too : )

Comment: No, it does not help because the sets $\{0,1,2,\dots,1^\prime\}$ and $\{1^\prime,0,1,2,\dots \}$ are just the same set, so it would not highlight the difference.

Comment: @Lmn6 Typo fixed.

Comment: I have to say that on the basis of this response, I would agree with Lmn6 so far.  How do { 0,1,2,…1′} and { 1′,0,1,2,…} denote different sets?  Looking around, I found this sentence "For example, 1+ω is not the same as ω+1; i.e., ω+1 = ord({0,1,2,...; 0}) but 1+ω is ord({0,0,1,2,3,...})=ω."  But, I don't see this either.  As I understand we could denote 0, 1, 2, ... by say N.  Then we have {0, N} and {N, 0} both of which equal N.  So, ord({0,1,2,...; 0})=ord({0,0,1,2,3,...}).  So, how do the sets here differ?

Comment: @Doug: In this answer, the notation $\{a,b,c,...\}$ is being used to represent an ordered list. Indeed, as *sets* $1+\omega$ and $\omega+1$ are equivalent, but it is the order that distinguishes them.

Comment: @JimConant Thanks Jim, that's right, it's a totally ordered set. Maybe you could suggest a better notation -- how are ordered lists usually denoted?

Comment: Ordered lists are usually denoted by round brackets, i.e. (..., ..., ...).

Comment: @Matt So, don't you just mean a special type of sequence?  If you do mean a special type of sequence, then you could write <0, 1, 2, ..., 1'> and <1', 0, 1, 2, ...>.

Comment: To all those fiddling notational issues, in the case of the natural numbers in the context of set theory $0\in1\in2\in\ldots\in\omega\in\ldots$, even as an unordered set there is still a natural order.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, but how do you justify the presence of $1^\prime$ in both sets? Where do you place it?

Answer (score 12):

I find pictures to help. The idea here is that $\omega$ is a limit ordinal and tacking on the ordinal $1$ after it is fundamentally different:

[image: omega]

[image: omega+1]

The picture for $\omega$ has a curved edge which indicates that it is a limit ordinal opposed to being a successor ordinal. When we tack on $1$ to the right of $\omega$ we have this ordinal $\omega+1$ that contains a limit ordinal which is not something that occurs in $\omega$. This means that $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ can't be isomorphic.

Can you use see why $1+\omega$ and $\omega+1$ aren't equal? Do you see why $1+\omega = \omega$?

Comment: Now it is very clear for me. Thanks tomcuchta.

Answer (score 4):

$\omega + 1$ has a limit point (i.e. $\omega$ — using the von Neumann definition $\omega + 1 = \omega \cup \lbrace\omega\rbrace$) in the order topology while $\omega$ is discrete in the order topology.

Answer (score 3):

Because the elements of $\omega$ are all finite, whereas $\omega + 1$ has one infinite element.